# Updating production database via DACPAC upgrade

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, production, dacpac, data-tier-applications

Using a DACPAC to upgrade a data-tier application database is an 'in-place process' as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/upgrade-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-ver15#BeforeYouBegin).

My question is, how do you go about updating your production databases?

Do you just apply the DACPAC directly to the production database, and then roll back if anything goes wrong?

Obviously you would test this first in a dev, test or staging environment but I'm wondering if there are any other options?

Comment: you can generate the script first, review it and then either re-run the deployment or simply execute the generated script

Answer (score 3):

We used dacpacs, but always tested the rollout against a nearly identical dev/test/uat system first. For really sensitive prod rollouts, sometimes I'd generate the change script/report first to make sure it was going to do what I expected.  If that looked good, I'd let it run. (sometimes the process needed advanced permissions from the CICD engine that I didn't have with my account)